# Javascript handle 2 forms in one page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 forms. I ask for an API-KEY int he first form to load values account in some inputs of the second form and submit it.

The first form:

```
<form id="formAPI" name="formAPI">
      <label for="" >API-KEY</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputApi" placeholder="XXX-XXX>
        <input id="continue" type="submit" value='Continue' onclick="submit_api()"/>
</form>
```

The second is like this:

```
    <form id="form2" >
          <label for="inputName3" >Name</label>
            <input type="text"  id="inputName3">
          <label for="selectDevices" >Device</label>
           *here devices have to be loaded automatically due to the API KEY*
            <select class="form-control" name ="device_s" id="id_devices">
                  <option value="1"> Device 1 </option>
                  <option value="2">Device 2</option>
                  <option value="3">Device 3</option>
            </select
            <input id="rule1" type="text" placeholder="Give a rule" /> 
            <input id="btn2" type="submit" value='Submit' /> 
   </form>
```

I have no choice if the page is reloaded outright or not. the essential is to preload some data from the second form via the API KEY of the first form.

Comment: The submission handler for the first form needs to 1. prevent the submission 2. run an AJAX call using the key and in the callback, insert the results into the second form. The easiest way to do (1) is to remove `<form>` from the first one, since you don't need it anyway.

Comment: I need the first form, because without the API KEY, i can't submit the second form. The idea is that, user have to choice a device, and do some manipulations but after choosing the good API KEY

Comment: You don't need `<form>` if you're using AJAX to populate the second form. The input and button are enough for that.

Comment: yeah ok, I'm trying what you suggested.

Answer (score -2):

You can use LocalDB js in your form1.
Create a js to write your api values and when submit the form2... receive this infos and fill where you need it.

Localdb support refresh and don't loose data.

Example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1021483/Localdb-js